# Jquery Datatables Individual column searching

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I am trying to apply [Individual column searching (select inputs)](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) for Datatables plugin in Jquery. I am using serverside processing, the data is loaded correctly from SQL Server into my table but when I want to select an input to filter a column based on that value, the filter is not working as you see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrmtO.png). 
When I select a country for example Austria, the data is not filtered to Austria.
Here is my index page

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset=utf-8" />
  <title> Datatables Individual column searching using PHP Ajax Jquery </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <h1 align="center">Datatables</h1>    
   <div class="table-responsive">
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Territory</th>
                <th>Market</th>
                <th>Entname</th>
                <th>MTM</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Territory</th>
                <th>Market</th>
                <th>Entname</th>
                <th>MTM</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {

      var dtable = $('#example').DataTable({  
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "deferRender": true,
            "lengthMenu": [ [25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"] ],
            "pageLength": -1,
            "lengthChange": true,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "columns": [
                {"data": "Country"},
                {"data": "Territory"},
                {"data": "Market"},
                {"data": "Entname"},
                {"data": "MTM"},
                {"data": "Qty"}
            ],
            "ajax": {
                url: 'fetch.php',
                type: 'POST'
            },   
            initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }

        });

      $(".dataTables_filter input")
    .unbind() 
    .bind("keyup change", function(e) { 
        if(this.value.length >= 1 && e.keyCode == 13) { dtable.search(this.value).draw(); }
        if(this.value == "") { dtable.search("").draw(); }
        return;
    });

} );
</script>
```

and here is my fetch.php

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


if (!empty($_POST) ) {

$ser="*****";
$db="*****";
$user="*****"; 
$pass="*****";
$dbDB = new PDO("odbc:Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;Server=*****;Database=*****;Port=1456", $user, $pass);
$MyTable="*****";

    function getData($sql){
        global $dbDB ;
        global $MyTable ;
        $result = $dbDB->query($sql);       
        $data= $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $data; }

        $res = $dbDB->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$MyTable);
        $recordsTotal = $res->fetchColumn();

    $draw = $_POST["draw"];
    $orderByColumnIndex  = $_POST['order'][0]['column'];
    $orderBy = $_POST['columns'][$orderByColumnIndex]['data'];
    $orderType = $_POST['order'][0]['dir']; 
    $start  = $_POST["start"];

    if ($_POST['length'] == -1) {$length = $recordsTotal;} 
    else {$length = $_POST['length'];}    


    if(!empty($_POST['search']['value'])){

        for($i=0 ; $i<count($_POST['columns']);$i++){
            $column = $_POST['columns'][$i]['data'];
            $where[]="$column like '%".$_POST['search']['value']."%'";
        }
        $where = "WHERE ".implode(" OR " , $where);


$sql = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s %s", $MyTable , $where);
$r = $dbDB->query($sql);
$recordsFiltered = $r->fetchColumn();

         $sql = sprintf("SELECT Country,Territory,Market,Entname,MTM,Qty FROM %s %s ORDER BY %s %s OFFSET %d ROWS FETCH NEXT %d ROWS ONLY", $MyTable , $where ,$orderBy, $orderType ,$start,$length);
        $data = getData($sql);
    }

    else {

        $sql = sprintf("SELECT Country,Territory,Market,Entname,MTM,Qty FROM %s ORDER BY %s %s OFFSET %d ROWS FETCH NEXT %d ROWS ONLY", $MyTable ,$orderBy, $orderType ,$start,$length);
          $data = getData($sql);
        $recordsFiltered = $recordsTotal;
    }

        $response = array(
        "draw" => intval($draw),
        "recordsTotal" => $recordsTotal,
        "recordsFiltered" => $recordsFiltered,
        "data" => $data );

    echo json_encode($response);
} 

else {
    echo "NO POST Query from DataTable";
}

?>
```

I believe that the issue is somewhere in the javascript part not the php file but just to show an overview how the data is populated into the table.

Any idea please where is the issue?

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: @Script47  no, any errors. that's the problem

Comment: Custom search values are in `$_POST['columns'][$i]['search']['value']` variables. You don't check them yet in your current script.

Comment: Check with your dev tool so you know what params your datatable sends to your PHP file.

Comment: I did exactly the same in my project. It is open-source so you can check there if you find something useful: https://github.com/fbaierl/bundeszirkus-server (nodejs instead of php though but the API is still the same). At work atm so no time to analyze your specific problem further, but maybe it helps you anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check below example

```js
   // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
 $('#item tfoot th').each( function () {
     var title = $(this).text();
     $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
 } );

// DataTable
 var otable = $('#item').DataTable();

 // Apply the search
 otable.columns().every( function () {
 
     var that = this;
     $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
         if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
             that
                 .search( this.value )
                 .draw();
         }
     } );
 } );
```

```css
 tfoot {
    display: table-header-group;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/DataTables-Jquery-Table-Plugin/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<table name="item" id="item" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Position</th>
               <th>Office</th>
               <th>Age</th>
               <th>Start date</th>
               <th>Salary</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tfoot>
           <tr>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Position</th>
               <th>Office</th>
               <th>Age</th>
               <th>Start date</th>
               <th>Salary</th>
           </tr>
       </tfoot>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
               <td>System Architect</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>61</td>
               <td>2011/04/25</td>
               <td>$320,800</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>Garrett Winters</td>
               <td>Accountant</td>
               <td>Tokyo</td>
               <td>63</td>
               <td>2011/07/25</td>
               <td>$170,750</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>Ashton Cox</td>
               <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>66</td>
               <td>2009/01/12</td>
               <td>$86,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
               <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>22</td>
               <td>2012/03/29</td>
               <td>$433,060</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>Airi Satou</td>
               <td>Accountant</td>
               <td>Tokyo</td>
               <td>33</td>
               <td>2008/11/28</td>
               <td>$162,700</td>
           </tr>
      </tbody>
          
   </table>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried already the solution but it worked just when i have a static table but when i load data from database the filter is not working

Answer (score 0):

what about datefilter search i.e enddate>startdate to this datatable.It would more convenient.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all.